# Cron runs an old version of sqlite with Python

Tags: python, sqlite, cron

I already read tons of replies and I think I focused the problem but I miss the last step.

I am running Python 3.7 on Linux and did the update of sqlite to version 3.35.4 downloading and compiling the code. After that, to make the last version visible inside Python I add a line with `vi` in a configuration file but unfortunately I am not able now to recover or remember the line neither the file. Anyway everything worked and making

```
import sqlite3
sqlite3.sqlite_version
```

I get me the correct sqlite version and the Python code run correctly.

The problem is that running the same Python code with cron I noticed that the old version of sqlite is used. How I can tell to cron to run the updated version of sqlite with Python?

Comment: Please show how you run Python scripts in your Terminal and also how you are starting the Python script in your crontab.

Comment: Terminal : `python mycode.py` where python links to 3.7 version.

In crontab: `* * * * * python /home/user/code_dir/mycode.py` where crontab takes the same Python version but an older sqlite (the standard one that comes with Python 3.7 and not the updated one). I tried in crontab to set some PATH and PYTHONPATH, maybe in the wrong way, without success.

Comment: In the Terminal, run `type python`. That will give you the full path to the Python interpreter which works. Use that same **full** path in `crontab`

Comment: No success unfortunately. The problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

```
!/bin/bash
cd /home/ec2-user/sqlite-autoconf-3380100/
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/
sudo make
sudo make install
sudo mv  /usr/bin/sqlite3 /usr/bin/sqlite3.bak
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/sqlite3 /usr/bin/sqlite3
sudo echo export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib">> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
cd /home/ec2-user/test
/usr/bin/python3 python.py
```

please have a look at above file which is my sh file for running python script.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33371381)